# I Want To Print Using ngx-print Library In Angular 14 But Css Is Not Applied

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table as you can see in the picture, when I want to print, it seems that the css properties are applied in the background, but unfortunately in the preview section, the css is not applied, what could be the reason for this? I turned on the background graphics feature but it still didn't fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUq6N.png)

My Html Code;

```
<div class="container-fuild ml-3 mr-3">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content *ngIf="reportingDataModel?.searchList.length>0 && reportingDataModel?.calculationList.length>0 ">
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="tableFixHead">
              <div class="table text-center">
                <table class="table table-bordered border border-secondary" id="save-stage48">
                  <thead id="tableHeadRow" role="row"> 
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>{{ 'MeasurementPoints' | translate }}</th>
                        <th   *ngFor="let searchList of reportingDataModel?.searchList; let i = index">
                          <div>{{ searchList.worOrderName }}</div>
                          <div>{{ searchList.measurementTypeName }}</div>
                          <div>{{ searchList.widthAndShrink }}</div>
                          <div *ngIf="searchList.reportType === 1">{{ searchList.sizeId }} {{ "Size" | translate }}</div>
                        </th>
                      <th>{{ 'averagetolerance' | translate }}</th>
                      <th   >
                        {{averageWidth}}
                        <br>
                        {{'decidetolerance' | translate}}
                      </th>
                      <th>{{ 'Description' | translate }}</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody >
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let calculation of reportingDataModel?.calculationList[0]; let i = index">
                      <tr >
                        <td style=""> {{i+1}} {{incomingName}} </td>
                        <td style="" [id]="calculation?.id">{{calculation?.measurementPointName}}</td>
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let calculations of reportingDataModel?.calculationList; let j = index">
                          <td>{{reportingDataModel?.calculationList[j][i].appliedPullTolerance}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <td >{{calculaterAverageTolerance(i)}}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td rowspan="3"> <textarea name="" id="" cols="15" rows="3"></textarea></td>
                      </tr>
  
                      <ng-container *ngIf="i <= reportingDataModel?.calculationList[0].length">
                          <tr >
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap">{{i+1}} {{incomingNameTwo}}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:start">{{calculation?.measurementPointName}}</td>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let calculations of reportingDataModel?.calculationList; let j = index">
                              <td>{{reportingDataModel?.calculationList[j][i].actualPullTolerance}}</td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <td>{{calculaterActualPullTolerance(i)}}</td>
                            <td><input type='number' style="width:50%"  step="0.1" [value]="total"/></td>
                          </tr>
  
                          <tr>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap">{{i+1}} {{"Avg."}}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:start">{{calculation?.measurementPointName}}</td>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let calculations of reportingDataModel?.calculationList; let j = index">
                              <td>{{reportingDataModel?.calculationList[j][i].averageValue}}</td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <td >{{calculaterAverageValue(i)}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                      </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

My Css Code ;

```
.table.text-center th,
.table.text-center td {
text-align: center;
}

#save-stage48 tbody tr td {
padding: 0 0.313rem;
height: 1.563rem;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}

#save-stage48, #save-stage48 td, #save-stage48 tr {
border: 0.031rem solid black;
}

#save-stage48 th {
border: 0.063rem dashed black;
}

#save-stage48 th {
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: center;
}

#save-stage48 td {
padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

#save-stage48 {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableFixHead {
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: auto;
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th {
background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) !important;
color: #666 !important;
}

.tableFixHead thead tr th {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}

#save-stage48 tbody tr:nth-child(3n+1) {
background-color: rgba(112, 128, 144, 1) !important;
color: white !important;
}

#save-stage48 tbody tr:nth-child(3n+2) {
background-color: rgba(148, 164, 179, 1) !important;
color: white !important;
}

#save-stage48 tbody tr:nth-child(3n+3) {
background-color: rgba(171, 186, 199, 1) !important;
color: white !important;
}

.dataTables_wrapper {
padding: 0 !important;
font-size: 0.688rem !important;
font-weight: bold;
}

#save-stage48 tbody tr:nth-of-type(3n) td {
border-bottom: 0.375rem solid white;
}

#save-stage48 tbody tr td:first-child {
border-left: 0.375rem solid white;
}

#save-stage48 tbody tr:nth-of-type(3n+1) td:last-child, tr:first-child td:last-child {
border-right: 0.375rem solid white;
border-bottom: 0.375rem solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button
  [useExistingCss]="true"
    printSectionId="print-section"
    ngxPrint>print</button>
```

Try this with `[useExistingCss]="true"`
source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print